# Recursively apply ACL permissions on Mac OS X (Server)?

Tags: mac-osx, permissions, filesystems, access-control-list, hfs+

For years I've used the strong-armed-duo of these two suckers...

```
sudo chmod +a "localadmin allow read,write,append,execute,\
 delete,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,\
 readsecurity,writesecurity,chown"

sudo chmod +a "localadmin allow list,search,add_file,add_subdirectory,\
 delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,\
 writeextattr,readsecurity,writesecurity,chown"
```

to, *for what I figured* was a **recursive**, and all-encompassing, whole-volume-go-ahead for each and every privilege available (for a user, `localadmin`).  Nice when I, `localadmin`, want to "do something" without a lot of whining about permissions, etc.

The beauty is, this method obviates the necessity to change ownership / group membership, or executable bit on anything.  **But is it recursive?**  I am beginning to think, it's not.  If so, how do I do THAT?  And how can one check something like this?   Adding this single-user to the ACL doesn't show up in the Finder, so…  Alright, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of those includes a target that I can see, so I'm not sure what you intend them to apply to.

The `chmod` manpage makes it pretty clear that `-R` applies things recursively, otherwise they apply to the named objects and nothing else.